# Gitlab PreReceive hook declined, but there are no hooks configured

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gitlab, hook

I have a 13.12.4 CE server running for several weeks.

Today out of the blue I started seeing push requests failing. There are no hooks configured on the server side.

`{"correlation_id":"01FBJQVYEHT2T7WVK40QD4J983","error":"GitLab: 500 Internal Server Error","grpc.meta.deadline_type":"none","grpc.method":"PreReceiveHook","grpc.request.fullMethod":"/gitaly.HookService/PreReceiveHook","grpc.request.glProjectPath":"ops/utilities","grpc.request.glRepository":"project-455","grpc.request.repoPath":"@hashed/f6/26/f626051bc94422f26f4b774a2bca105e122df36a2f32f51bd7ee470daa620b0b.git","grpc.request.repoStorage":"default","grpc.request.topLevelGroup":"@hashed","grpc.service":"gitaly.HookService","grpc.start_time":"2021-07-27T01:04:36.392Z","level":"warning","msg":"stopping transaction because pre-receive hook failed","peer.address":"@","pid":8500,"span.kind":"server","system":"grpc","time":"2021-07-27T01:04:36.438Z"}`

I could not see any errors so I first tried to stop/start services - Had issues starting services.

Next I restarted the EC2 instance and everything started working again.

Any ideas.

Comment: Happened again 10 days later :-(

Comment: Also we are not using LFS so why would I get stuff like this

Comment: GRPC::Internal (13:could not read LFS pointers: invalid LFS pointer candidate line "1c1b440f216d222be77b80ac76def4756d2e8b6d missing". debug_error_string:{"created":"@1628263312.129487528","description":"Error received from peer unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/gitaly.socket","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1055,"grpc_message":"could not read LFS pointers: invalid LFS pointer candidate line "1c1b440f216d222be77b80ac76def4756d2e8b6d missing"","grpc_status":13}):